# Control Upload Location on Google Drive for Scans

Tags: google-drive

Google Drive on Android has the really helpful scan feature which I use all the time. However, it would be really great to be able to control where the default location for those files in Drive is.

Is this possible, if so how do you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the Drive Scan widget to your home screen.

[image]

Then it will ask you where you want subsequent uploads to go.

[image]

Then after that you can just use that shortcut to scan things and they'll go to that default folder.